# Selenium Wait does it wait the delay or ignores it if it finds it faster?

Tags: python, selenium

Hello guys I have a simple question, for instance im using this code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".test-name")))
print("ELEMENT FOUND")
```

Does it wait explicitly 20 seconds, or does it wait only until it finds the element and waits a maximum of 20 seconds if not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It wait only until it finds the element and waits a maximum of 20 seconds if not found*

*Wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.*

[WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html)

*This waits up to 20 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless it finds the element to return within 20 seconds. WebDriverWait by default calls the ExpectedCondition every 500 milliseconds until it returns successfully. A successful return is for ExpectedCondition type is Boolean return true or not null return value for all other ExpectedCondition types.*

*[Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)*

Comment: But the next code will only get executed once it finds the element correct?

Comment: Correct or you will get  error ‘exceptions.NoSuchElementException:’

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example and documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Quoting:
*"This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless it finds the element to return within 10 seconds."*

Comment: But the next code will only get executed once it finds the element correct?

Comment: It will either execute the next line of code if it finds the element or throw a TimeoutException if it doesn't find it within the specified time frame.